# How to create an interactivs JS (vanilla) background animation

Tags: javascript, animation, dom

Trying to create an animated element (div) appear on background on page load and then on scroll (the first animation disappears and the second slides in).

As a beginner, I managed to create one simple, choppy animation (code below) but I can't figure out how to make it smooth, how to make it disappear on scroll down and how to place another animation instead of this one.

Although there are many questions that I need to find answers to, 
the one i'm asking is -

How do I use the animation again in a different place ? Let's say vh height is 700px so after user scrolled those 700px I want the animation to slide in again from the top right corner.

```js
    function bgAnimation () {
      let element = document.getElementById("bg");
      let pos = -800;
      let id = setInterval(frame, 1);

      function frame () {
        if (pos == -300) {clearInterval(id);} else {

            pos++;
            element.style.right = pos + 'px';
            element.style.top = pos + 'px';
            element.style.paddingLeft = '150px';

        }
      }
    }
    
    window.addEventListener("load", bgAnimation);
```

```html
    <body id="body">
    <section>
    <div id="cvs">
    <div id="bg"></div>
    </div>

    </section>
    </body>
```

Comment: It looks like you're off to a good start, but you've asked at least three questions: "I can't figure out how to make it smooth, how to make it disappear on scroll down and how to place another animation instead of this one." You're probably not going to get high-quality answers unless you edit your post down to a single question, with details specific to that particular problem.

Comment: @NicolásAlarcónR, please don't edit in "Thanks". See [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/194720)

Comment: Ty. I edited the post with a single question at the end. @Jordan Running